# Angular $resource action return $resource of different class

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

So I have a `services.js` that looks something like this.

```
.factory('User', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/users/:id/', {'id': '@id'}, {
    groups: {
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/users/:id/groups',
        isArray: true
    }
  });
})

.factory('Group', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/groups/:id/', {'id': '@id'}, {
    update: {
      method: 'PUT'
    }
  });
})
```

Users in the db have an implicit relationship to Groups via a JSONField of ids (implicit in that it is not an explicit one2m or m2m). I have a custom endpoint on my api server `'/api/users/:id/groups'` that returns a serialized array of Group instances. My issue is that the `User::groups` action on the angular side is returning an array of the Group instances **BUT** with the actions of the **USER** resource instead of the **GROUP** resource. Is there any way for the custom action of a $resource to return an instance of a $resource from a different class?

Thanks!